# Tint an image in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, image, reactjs, web, tint

I have a bunch of icons where on each icon, the background is transparent and the icon itself is filled in white. I would like to tint the color of these icons somehow in ReactJS. The colors will be pulled from `this.state.color` which in my scenario, is a color that a user can choose from the front end. For example, if I choose the color red, the icon will turn red while the background remains transparent. Is this possible in ReactJS without using a plugin?

Comment: Inverse the transparency of the icon file, then set the background-color of the <img> to the color you want.

Comment: I do that but theres a gray background hover effect on the entire row that the icons are in (For UX mainly). Therefore, when a user hovers over the row, a slight white background can be seen from the icon but the icon renders perfectly fine with the desired color. It's a minor thing but I was hoping there was a better way of doing this.

Comment: It's not ideal but you could also change the icon graphic on hovering. The only alternative I know of is to use <canvas> and `ImageData`.

Comment: Hm ok. I will look into canvas and ImageData more if there's not better solution

Comment: You can actually use `<svg>`s, and a library like http://snapsvg.io/