# Tint images in ReactJS

Tags: image, reactjs, css, inline-styles

So I have this React component where I pass the background image and the colour it should get as a tint via props. It looks like this:

```
this.props.background = 'https://picsum.photos/650';
this.props.color = '#E74C3C';

<div style={{
                ...defaultStyle,
                background: 'url(' + this.props.background + '), linearGradient(' + this.props.color + ',' + this.props.color')'
            }}>
```

Problem is that it throws an error saying that it can't be compiled. Can you tell me how else I would apply the tint using css inline-styles?

Comment: Similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41473264/tint-an-image-in-reactjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the linearGradient using `rgba()` format, but it might be better to use an overlay container with the opacity set low, and pass the tint colour in using props. I've built a small example using overlay on CodeSandBox - [View Sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/2v3oxz44qp)